# how to check windows icon file for image quality

Tags: windows, icons

I have recently used an icon file received from our marketing team.  The icon file when opened in resource editor (Visual Studio 2008) looks like this.

[image]

The same file when **opened-and-saved** in **[IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/)** appears correctly in resource editor.
[image]

My marketing team uses some tools ([Picture2Icon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picture2icon/id412560610?mt=12) ) in Mac and produces the icon file which appears to be *corrupt* or *not fully correct*.  The same file saved by IcoFx seems to be correct.   What is causing the ICOFX out to be correct?

The result is the exe shows bad icons.  The exact case where the image is bad is not clear- It is reported in case where color quality is set to be 'medium' **(windows XP)**. It is worse when executable  is "selected" in windows explorer.

[image]

Here is one icon that shows problem: https://github.com/jayanmn/icontest/blob/master/icontest.ico

Full sample code to create exe is at  https://github.com/jayanmn/icontest/

So question is  given an ico file, how can I ensure that it works fine on WindowsXP, Windows Vista and Windows7?

Comment: When you actually embed it as the icon resource for an EXE, does it appear correct in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Seems that VS only handle PNG based ICO, just not BMP ? Perhaps it is not in the expected 'Windows BMP' format?

Comment: @selbie : The exe will show bad icons in select setting- specifically in 16bit color (medium color)

Comment: If you supply this ico-file - answer may appears faster )

Comment: Updated with sample icon and sample code to create exe.

Comment: The icon has corrupt monochrome bitmaps, the ones that contain a mask that determines what pixels of the icon image are transparent.  You'll need a better icon editor.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: thanks. Is there a programmatic way to find more about corrupt mono chrome bitmaps?

Comment: The icons in the file all use the alpha channel (transparency) and VS does not handle RGBA icons, only 1, 4, 8, 24 bit images (no alpha). However, the icons should display fine with Windows Vista and higher. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the icon after compilation with a resource editor?

Comment: FYI: A Picture2Icon buyer reports: *This app does not work as advertised. Trying to export png's as .ICO files renders a useless product.*

Comment: @ arttronics - I noticed it. It was not clear when the message was posted on the site.

Comment: @Jayan, did you have a chance to remove compression on layer 5 of icon that should solve your issue?

Comment: @arttronics - Yes, saving a bad icon with gimp with box unchecked seems to have fixed it. As I wrote earlier 'as a solution' saving with icofx.

Comment: I am not sure if icofx can set the compression per each layer separately as GIMP can do. At least it's clear what icofx is doing, which is removing compression on all layers. Glad this is sorted out.

Comment: @ arttronics: It looks likes the order in which the images are stored in ico may be important.  need to try more.

Comment: @Jayan, sorry did not see this comment before. In Windows XP, I manually adjusted the size of icons on system level via Display Properties, Appearance and working down to Icon Size. I set to 16px, so that Layer 6 should show up... and it did. All sizes show up depending on View Mode. I did not test Layer 5 size of 256px since I don't want to mess with the Windows Registry to force that type of icon size, but as mentioned it's not an issue with the icon apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took a good look at your `icontest.ico` file provided from the GitHub website and discovered that the solution is an easy fix.

First, let me illustrate the problem as I see it on a **Windows XP 32bit System** using the freeware [**IrfanView**](http://www.irfanview.com/) software which is an **excellent** image viewer for this task.

Here is a composite shot I made **illustrating the error for 5 of 6 layers** as seen using IrfanView:

[image]

To fix the above `icontest.ico` file, one would think frames 1,2,3,4 and 6 are bad. But the opposite is true! It turns out that **frame 5** is the culprit!.

Specifically, frame 5 has compression set on this frame which is causing the issue.

The actual fix that's required is to merely ***re-save*** the `icontest.ico` file without compressing that layer. For this task, the freeware [**GIMP**](http://www.gimp.org/) application which is an excellent **image editor** is perfect for this task.

Just re-save the icon file with **GIMP** but remove the compression for the **5th** layer as shown below:

[image]

The final result is a properly rendered **icontestResaved.ico** as seen in IrfanView (*Tip: To view frames of an icon file in IrfanView, use the Red Arrows that's next to the frame number, i.e. 1/6*):
[image]

The best way to ensure that the file works in different Windows Operating System's is to actually have a machine available, as the rendering engine is unique and emulators might not work as intended.

**For the curious:** Setting *all layers* to be compressed in GIMP resulted in a icon that was **not viewable** in Windows Explorer.

**Tip:** To view the reference images above at **original size**, right mouse-click and choose View Image.

**Status Update:** Consider installing [**Axialis IconWorkshop™ Lite Version 6.3.1.1**](http://www.axialis.com/download/iwlite.html) to handle all your icon development workflow needs. It's a free **Visual Studio 2008 Plugin** provided by Axialis themselves!

Comment: @ arttronics  : Thanks, My version of IrfanView does not open ICO. What is the specific plugin to be used?

Comment: For my Windows PC, I downloaded IfranView [**HERE**](http://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm) and they provide a plugin pack [**HERE**](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm). It should then open any .ico file easily, even corrupt ones.

Comment: Besides IfanView to view the icons, GIMP works too and that program is also used to re-save the icons correctly.